# Deploying item/project VS2010 templates for all users

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, templates, deployment

I know how to deploy VS template to the user's Documents\VS2010\Templates folder, but is it possible to deploy templates globally, so that all users have access to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard templates are located in:

```
%ProgramFiles%/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/ProjectTemplates
                                                       /ItemTemplates
```